# How to share sub folders across parent folders with users such that they can access and traverse to the subfolders?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, sharing

I have a folder hierarchy as explained below:

At the top level I have one folder for each client. Example: Mercedes, BMW, Audi, Suzuki, etc

Each client folder has subfolder for the parts Dealer. Example: EuroCar, CarPartsUK, PartsForLess, etc.

A dealer can have sub folder in multiple client folders. For example: EuroCar can be in both BMW as well as Audi.

I want to share the client folder with the respective client. And the dealer folders with respective dealers.

I have enabled external sharing.

What is the best way to share this such that when a dealer opens a folder, they should be able to traverse the hierarchy to go into their folder across clients.